# How do I manually edit the source code of a web part?

Tags: list, web-part

I am trying to edit the List web part. I want to add page numbers rather than item numbers.

I found what seems to be a couple straightforward tutorials, but I can't figure out how to get to the source code so I can paste/edit what they are trying to tell me to do.

Comment: Try downloading SharePoint Designer. That's your first step.

Comment: Right, I have it installed. And I'm looking at the .aspx site page. I found the block of code that has the List. Where do I go from here

Comment: I'm trying to better understand the question. What are you trying to count or display? For what its worth if you have a list that has many items you can specify how many items display on a page or in the web part by default. SharePoint then adds some dynamic page controls to help users go to the next page of items.

Comment: I am trying to change what is shown at the bottom of the list app. Watch the gif I linked below. As I scroll, I want it to have "page numbers". That's it. I just change want to change the text in between the 2 buttons but there is no option in the "edit web part" tab to do this. 

https://gyazo.com/15644e05fa860a31b54c977582f31019